# Why did many lifters of the past use to lower the bar in their clean/snatch whilst now they drop it?

Tags: weightlifting, bodybuilding, olympic-weightlifting, snatch, power-cleans

I've noticed that in some old competitions there were many athletes who did not drop the bar, but instead lowered it.

You may see them in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zIo-vJIcccs).

Why has this habit changed? Nowadays, all the people I talk with assume that you must absolutely drop the bar in clean and snatch. And on the web, I have found just one guide about how to lower the bar in [those exercises](https://www.catalystathletics.com/article/1709/Lowering-the-Bar-Between-Reps-in-the-Snatch-Clean-and-Jerk/).

Ps: my interest in lowering the bar is because I don't have bumpers and with my cast iron plates I'd damage my floor if I drop them. But also because I'd like to learn also the eccentric phase of clean and snatch. Just for curiosity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rubber "bumper" plates were not invented until 1967.[<sup>1</sup>](https://wikitia.com/wiki/Eleiko)<sup>,</sup>[<sup>2</sup>](https://www.facebook.com/eleiko/photos/a.420385726570/10155251792456571) Prior to that, only steel and iron plates were available, and dropping those from overhead would likely damage the equipment or platform.